# How to capture the List of removed items from Java 8 Stream filtering?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am using the following expression to filter a list of people whose birthday matches criteria.

```
List<Person> matchingPeople = people.stream()
.filter(p -> dateFilters.stream()
    .anyMatch(df -> 
       numOfDaysBetween(p.getBirthDate(), df.getDate())  < df.getDiffRange()
    )
)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`Collectors.toList()` returns the list of people matching the criteria. I am wondering how to capture the list of people that got removed for debugging/logging purpose. One possible way is to run the list through another filter, but that will be inefficient. Can we do it in the same filter ?

Comment: Well if you don't want to filter any elements out, then you can just map, group by the result, and reduce into two different output-lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in the same `filter` call :

```
 List<Person> matchingPeople = 
     people.stream()
           .filter(p -> {
              if (dateFilters.stream()
                             .anyMatch(df -> numOfDaysBetween(p.getBirthDate(), df.getDate()) < df.getDiffRange()
)) 
              {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  //you can add here code to log elements that don't pass the filter
                  //or you can add these elements to an external List
                  return false;
              }
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another alternative is to partition the input List into two Lists based on the filter predicate :

```
Map<Boolean, List<Person>> partition =
     people.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> <same code as in your filter method call>));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove matching people from people collection:

```
people.removeAll(matchingPeople);
```

Comment: This approach can get really confusing because it changes the state of the original collection - use with care / caution / better yet not at all.